# Include a digit to automatically generate password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-membership

I'm using following code snippet to generate password automatically

```
string Password = Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 1);
```

but here sometimes its generating password without digit values then I'm getting following error

> Passwords must have at least one digit ('0'-'9').

How can I upgrade above code to generate with digit value

Comment: Are you using it to generate passwords for other sites? If so, that's not what it's designed for. Also, if you're forcing users to use at least one number in their password... don't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can further process the generated password, if it doesn't contain a number, you randomly change one of them to a number like this:

```
if (!Password.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x))){
    Random rand = new Random();
    char[] pass = Password.ToCharArray();
    pass[rand.Next(Password.Length)] = Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(10) + '0');
    Password = new string(pass);
}
```

If you want to avoid for not having the lower character, you could add another check such as:

```
if (!Password.Any(x => char.IsLower(x))) {
    //Do similarly but using rand.Next(26) + 'a' instead of rand.Next(10) + '0'
}
```

And if you want to avoid the position that has been changed as a number to be the position you change as a lower character, simply store `rand.Next(Password.Length)` in the first number generation and avoid having the same value for the second.

Or, more robustly, we could define a `List` of `nonSelectedIndexes` and pick-and-remove a random number from it every time we perform a substitution operation:

```
List<int> nonSelectedIndexes = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, Password.Length));
Random rand = new Random();

if (!Password.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x))) { //does not contain digit
    char[] pass = Password.ToCharArray();
    int pos = nonSelectedIndexes[rand.Next(nonSelectedIndexes.Count)];
    nonSelectedIndexes.Remove(pos);
    pass[pos] = Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(10) + '0');
    Password = new string(pass);
}

if (!Password.Any(x => char.IsLower(x))) { //does not contain lower
    char[] pass = Password.ToCharArray();
    int pos = nonSelectedIndexes[rand.Next(nonSelectedIndexes.Count)];
    nonSelectedIndexes.Remove(pos);
    pass[pos] = Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(26) + 'a');
    Password = new string(pass);
}

if (!Password.Any(x => char.IsUpper(x))) { //does not contain upper
    char[] pass = Password.ToCharArray();
    int pos = nonSelectedIndexes[rand.Next(nonSelectedIndexes.Count)];
    nonSelectedIndexes.Remove(pos);
    pass[pos] = Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(26) + 'A');
    Password = new string(pass);
}

//And so on
//Do likewise to any other condition
```

Note: Please [consider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) [Mr. SilverlightFox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413180/silverlightfox) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985596/include-a-digit-to-automatically-generate-password/34985643#comment57747832_34985643) if you use this for anything security-related.

Comment: can this code include new number without changing existing number ?

Comment: @Chathz this code will only be **run** if there is no number at all, Look at the `if (!Password.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x)))` condition. This `Random` is to give uncertainty as to where the position of the Password will be changed to number and the number it uses. You could define it more exactly if you wish so.

Comment: Actually this `string Password` should be ` model.Password` , since I need to clear the description I've used it, now i try to integrate your code getting error in this line `model.Password[pos]`

Comment: `Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Comment: @Chathz updated. Please take a look. Note the `+ '0'` I added

Comment: You shouldn't use `Random` for anything security related, as it is predictable. Use [rngcryptoserviceprovider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. In this case the damage is limited because you are only changing one character to a random number, however be careful with using predictable values.

Comment: @SilverlightFox noted. Thanks for the input. I updated my answer by putting up a reference to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Random numGenerator = new Random();

...

string Password = Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 1);

if(!Regex.IsMatch(Password, "\\d"))
   Password += numGenerator.GetNext(0, 10);
```

Comment: Do I need this `random` method ?

Comment: You need it or some other mechanism to add a random digit to the string (unless you always want to add a constant digit to the end).

Comment: since some compile time errors I ended your code like this , but `Random numGenerator = new Random();

 Subsidary_DropDownListEn(model.Subsidary_ID);

 model.Password = Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 1);

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(model.Password, "\\d"))
                model.Password += numGenerator.Next(0, 10);` getting this error `Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z').`

Comment: Please see [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985596/include-a-digit-to-automatically-generate-password/34985643?noredirect=1#comment57747832_34985643) regarding predictable random values.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple approach:

```
string Password = Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 1);
Password = Password + "1"
```

It would be helpful that when you generate temporary password, if you prompt your user to change their password at login.